# sending text data over network in java

Tags: java, networking, serialization

I have a use case where we have two different java programs doing:

1. First java program has to send some parameters to invoke the second java program.
2. First java program has to send datastream to the second program.

The approach that I have in mind is:

1. Use Socket class where second java program is socket server and first java program socket client.
2. First java program serializes the arguments needed by second java class to initialize it's class object that performs the task. Second java program de-serializes it.
3. Now the first java program has to send data that second java program on another machine would work on. The First program can send data as a `BufferedWriter` object but how will server know that it is receving the arguments and after arguments, it has got the stream to work on ?

Any other inputs for the approach are greatly appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

check out here, its nicely explained. 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html